# C# PowerShell application Exception

Tags: c#, powershell

I am running Powershell commands within C# to get mailbox exchange folder delegates.

I am using the following 2 commands:

```
string scriptText = "Get-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity \"" + email + ":\\calendar\" | ? { ($_.user.tostring() -notlike \"Anonymous\") -and ($_.user.tostring() -notlike \"Default\") } | select User, AccessRights"

using (var powerShell = PowerShell.Create()) {

    powerShell.AddScript(scriptText);
    powerShell.Runspace = Runspace;

    var iAsyncResult = powerShell.BeginInvoke();

    psData = powerShell.EndInvoke(iAsyncResult);
}

string scriptText = "Get-MailboxPermission -Identity " + email + " | ? {($_.user.tostring() -ne “NT AUTHORITY\\SELF”) –and ($_.user.tostring() -ne “DOMAINDiscovery Management”) -and $_.IsInherited -eq $false -and ($_.AccessRights -match \"" + accessRights + "\")} | select User, AccessRights";

using (var powerShell = PowerShell.Create()) {

    powerShell.AddScript(scriptText);
    powerShell.Runspace = Runspace;

    var iAsyncResult = powerShell.BeginInvoke();

    psData = powerShell.EndInvoke(iAsyncResult);
}
```

At random intervals I get the following exception:
**hostexception: a command that prompts the user failed because the host program or the command type does not support user interaction. the host was attempting to request confirmation with the following message: enter your credentials**

I have no user prompts or anything in my commands. Does anyone know why my script is failing?

Comment: Is it possible you are looking up account info to which you dont have access to

Comment: I have super user access to the mailboxes across the domain

Comment: Use a try catch statement to capture the account that is throwing the error and then find out what's different about the account.

Comment: I catch the exception, shut the Runspace down, dispose of it and then reconnect when I get the exception. I am able to then reach the mailbox I am unable to reach prior to getting the exception. So I don't think it is an access thing.

Comment: It turns out that when I run this straight from PowerShell I get an implicit remoting error. It then prompts for the username/password. That must be happening behind the scenes in C# which gets reported to me as the original error. I am not sure what to do about the Implicit remoting error.

Comment: I can suggest an auto retry of 3 retried before failing with try catch

Comment: I have some updates:
1) It definitely has something to do with permissions. Some of my co-workers can run it fine on their machines.but it still does not work for me
3) I did try the try/catch disconnect/reconnect. That works for a little bit and then when it has to retry again it fails with the same error and further reconnects also throw the same error.

I ran it straight in PowerShell. It seems C# masks the error. The actual error is something to do with implicit remoting.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it runs fine when the shell is run as admin.